# How can I access jquery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, swipe

---

I have the following jquery file... 
how can I directly access **$navPrev** and **$navNext** functions directly in my inline script or on any event I want. for example:

```
    $("a").swipe( {
    //Generic swipe handler for all directions
        swipe:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
             // My code here to move next or previous based on swipe action.
         ); 
             },
});
```

I am basically tying to add jquery swipe feature to scroll the the slider. and for that I need to be able to access the next and previous functions directly.

```
(function( $, undefined ) {

 // Gallery object.

$.Gallery               = function( options, element ) {

    this.$el    = $( element );
    this._init( options );

};

$.Gallery.defaults      = {
    current     : 0,    // index of current item
    autoplay    : false,// slideshow on / off
    interval    : 2000  // time between transitions
};

$.Gallery.prototype     = {
    _init               : function( options ) {

        this.options        = $.extend( true, {}, $.Gallery.defaults, options );

        // support for 3d / 2d transforms and transitions
        this.support3d      = Modernizr.csstransforms3d;
        this.support2d      = Modernizr.csstransforms;
        this.supportTrans   = Modernizr.csstransitions;

        this.$wrapper       = this.$el.find('.dg-wrapper');

        this.$items         = this.$wrapper.children();
        this.itemsCount     = this.$items.length;

        this.$nav           = this.$el.find('nav');
        this.$navPrev       = this.$nav.find('.dg-prev');
        this.$navNext       = this.$nav.find('.dg-next');

        // minimum of 3 items
        if( this.itemsCount < 3 ) {

            this.$nav.remove();
            return false;

        }   

        this.current        = this.options.current;

        this.isAnim         = false;

        this.$items.css({
            'opacity'   : 0,
            'visibility': 'hidden'
        });

        this._validate();

        this._layout();

        // load the events
        this._loadEvents();

        // slideshow
        if( this.options.autoplay ) {

            this._startSlideshow();

        }

    },
    _validate           : function() {

        if( this.options.current < 0 || this.options.current > this.itemsCount - 1 ) {

            this.current = 0;

        }   

    },
    _layout             : function() {

        // current, left and right items
        this._setItems();

        // current item is not changed
        // left and right one are rotated and translated
        var leftCSS, rightCSS, currentCSS;

        if( this.support3d && this.supportTrans ) {

            leftCSS     = {
                '-webkit-transform' : 'translateX(-350px) translateZ(-200px) rotateY(45deg)',
                '-moz-transform'    : 'translateX(-350px) translateZ(-200px) rotateY(45deg)',
                '-o-transform'      : 'translateX(-350px) translateZ(-200px) rotateY(45deg)',
                '-ms-transform'     : 'translateX(-350px) translateZ(-200px) rotateY(45deg)',
                'transform'         : 'translateX(-350px) translateZ(-200px) rotateY(45deg)'
            };

            rightCSS    = {
                '-webkit-transform' : 'translateX(350px) translateZ(-200px) rotateY(-45deg)',
                '-moz-transform'    : 'translateX(350px) translateZ(-200px) rotateY(-45deg)',
                '-o-transform'      : 'translateX(350px) translateZ(-200px) rotateY(-45deg)',
                '-ms-transform'     : 'translateX(350px) translateZ(-200px) rotateY(-45deg)',
                'transform'         : 'translateX(350px) translateZ(-200px) rotateY(-45deg)'
            };

            leftCSS.opacity     = 1;
            leftCSS.visibility  = 'visible';
            rightCSS.opacity    = 1;
            rightCSS.visibility = 'visible';

        }
        else if( this.support2d && this.supportTrans ) {

            leftCSS     = {
                '-webkit-transform' : 'translate(-350px) scale(0.8)',
                '-moz-transform'    : 'translate(-350px) scale(0.8)',
                '-o-transform'      : 'translate(-350px) scale(0.8)',
                '-ms-transform'     : 'translate(-350px) scale(0.8)',
                'transform'         : 'translate(-350px) scale(0.8)'
            };

            rightCSS    = {
                '-webkit-transform' : 'translate(350px) scale(0.8)',
                '-moz-transform'    : 'translate(350px) scale(0.8)',
                '-o-transform'      : 'translate(350px) scale(0.8)',
                '-ms-transform'     : 'translate(350px) scale(0.8)',
                'transform'         : 'translate(350px) scale(0.8)'
            };

            currentCSS  = {
                'z-index'           : 999
            };

            leftCSS.opacity     = 1;
            leftCSS.visibility  = 'visible';
            rightCSS.opacity    = 1;
            rightCSS.visibility = 'visible';

        }

        this.$leftItm.css( leftCSS || {} );
        this.$rightItm.css( rightCSS || {} );

        this.$currentItm.css( currentCSS || {} ).css({
            'opacity'   : 1,
            'visibility': 'visible'
        }).addClass('dg-center');

    },
    _setItems           : function() {

        this.$items.removeClass('dg-center');

        this.$currentItm    = this.$items.eq( this.current );
        this.$leftItm       = ( this.current === 0 ) ? this.$items.eq( this.itemsCount - 1 ) : this.$items.eq( this.current - 1 );
        this.$rightItm      = ( this.current === this.itemsCount - 1 ) ? this.$items.eq( 0 ) : this.$items.eq( this.current + 1 );

        if( !this.support3d && this.support2d && this.supportTrans ) {

            this.$items.css( 'z-index', 1 );
            this.$currentItm.css( 'z-index', 999 );

        }

        // next & previous items
        if( this.itemsCount > 3 ) {

            // next item
            this.$nextItm       = ( this.$rightItm.index() === this.itemsCount - 1 ) ? this.$items.eq( 0 ) : this.$rightItm.next();
            this.$nextItm.css( this._getCoordinates('outright') );

            // previous item
            this.$prevItm       = ( this.$leftItm.index() === 0 ) ? this.$items.eq( this.itemsCount - 1 ) : this.$leftItm.prev();
            this.$prevItm.css( this._getCoordinates('outleft') );

        }

    },
    _loadEvents         : function() {

        var _self   = this;

        this.$navPrev.on( 'click.gallery', function( event ) {

            if( _self.options.autoplay ) {

                clearTimeout( _self.slideshow );
                _self.options.autoplay  = false;

            }

            _self._navigate('prev');

            return false;

        });

        this.$navNext.on( 'click.gallery', function( event ) {

            if( _self.options.autoplay ) {

                clearTimeout( _self.slideshow );
                _self.options.autoplay  = false;

            }

            _self._navigate('next');
            return false;

        });

        this.$wrapper.on( 'webkitTransitionEnd.gallery transitionend.gallery OTransitionEnd.gallery', function( event ) {

            _self.$currentItm.addClass('dg-center');
            _self.$items.removeClass('dg-transition');
            _self.isAnim    = false;

        });

    },
    _getCoordinates     : function( position ) {

        if( this.support3d && this.supportTrans ) {

            switch( position ) {
                case 'outleft':
                    return {
                        '-webkit-transform' : 'translateX(-450px) translateZ(-300px) rotateY(45deg)',
                        '-moz-transform'    : 'translateX(-450px) translateZ(-300px) rotateY(45deg)',
                        '-o-transform'      : 'translateX(-450px) translateZ(-300px) rotateY(45deg)',
                        '-ms-transform'     : 'translateX(-450px) translateZ(-300px) rotateY(45deg)',
                        'transform'         : 'translateX(-450px) translateZ(-300px) rotateY(45deg)',
                        'opacity'           : 0,
                        'visibility'        : 'hidden'
                    };
                    break;
                case 'outright':
                    return {
                        '-webkit-transform' : 'translateX(450px) translateZ(-300px) rotateY(-45deg)',
                        '-moz-transform'    : 'translateX(450px) translateZ(-300px) rotateY(-45deg)',
                        '-o-transform'      : 'translateX(450px) translateZ(-300px) rotateY(-45deg)',
                        '-ms-transform'     : 'translateX(450px) translateZ(-300px) rotateY(-45deg)',
                        'transform'         : 'translateX(450px) translateZ(-300px) rotateY(-45deg)',
                        'opacity'           : 0,
                        'visibility'        : 'hidden'
                    };
                    break;
                case 'left':
                    return {
                        '-webkit-transform' : 'translateX(-350px) translateZ(-200px) rotateY(45deg)',
                        '-moz-transform'    : 'translateX(-350px) translateZ(-200px) rotateY(45deg)',
                        '-o-transform'      : 'translateX(-350px) translateZ(-200px) rotateY(45deg)',
                        '-ms-transform'     : 'translateX(-350px) translateZ(-200px) rotateY(45deg)',
                        'transform'         : 'translateX(-350px) translateZ(-200px) rotateY(45deg)',
                        'opacity'           : 1,
                        'visibility'        : 'visible'
                    };
                    break;
                case 'right':
                    return {
                        '-webkit-transform' : 'translateX(350px) translateZ(-200px) rotateY(-45deg)',
                        '-moz-transform'    : 'translateX(350px) translateZ(-200px) rotateY(-45deg)',
                        '-o-transform'      : 'translateX(350px) translateZ(-200px) rotateY(-45deg)',
                        '-ms-transform'     : 'translateX(350px) translateZ(-200px) rotateY(-45deg)',
                        'transform'         : 'translateX(350px) translateZ(-200px) rotateY(-45deg)',
                        'opacity'           : 1,
                        'visibility'        : 'visible'
                    };
                    break;
                case 'center':
                    return {
                        '-webkit-transform' : 'translateX(0px) translateZ(0px) rotateY(0deg)',
                        '-moz-transform'    : 'translateX(0px) translateZ(0px) rotateY(0deg)',
                        '-o-transform'      : 'translateX(0px) translateZ(0px) rotateY(0deg)',
                        '-ms-transform'     : 'translateX(0px) translateZ(0px) rotateY(0deg)',
                        'transform'         : 'translateX(0px) translateZ(0px) rotateY(0deg)',
                        'opacity'           : 1,
                        'visibility'        : 'visible'
                    };
                    break;
            };

        }
        else if( this.support2d && this.supportTrans ) {

            switch( position ) {
                case 'outleft':
                    return {
                        '-webkit-transform' : 'translate(-450px) scale(0.7)',
                        '-moz-transform'    : 'translate(-450px) scale(0.7)',
                        '-o-transform'      : 'translate(-450px) scale(0.7)',
                        '-ms-transform'     : 'translate(-450px) scale(0.7)',
                        'transform'         : 'translate(-450px) scale(0.7)',
                        'opacity'           : 0,
                        'visibility'        : 'hidden'
                    };
                    break;
                case 'outright':
                    return {
                        '-webkit-transform' : 'translate(450px) scale(0.7)',
                        '-moz-transform'    : 'translate(450px) scale(0.7)',
                        '-o-transform'      : 'translate(450px) scale(0.7)',
                        '-ms-transform'     : 'translate(450px) scale(0.7)',
                        'transform'         : 'translate(450px) scale(0.7)',
                        'opacity'           : 0,
                        'visibility'        : 'hidden'
                    };
                    break;
                case 'left':
                    return {
                        '-webkit-transform' : 'translate(-350px) scale(0.8)',
                        '-moz-transform'    : 'translate(-350px) scale(0.8)',
                        '-o-transform'      : 'translate(-350px) scale(0.8)',
                        '-ms-transform'     : 'translate(-350px) scale(0.8)',
                        'transform'         : 'translate(-350px) scale(0.8)',
                        'opacity'           : 1,
                        'visibility'        : 'visible'
                    };
                    break;
                case 'right':
                    return {
                        '-webkit-transform' : 'translate(350px) scale(0.8)',
                        '-moz-transform'    : 'translate(350px) scale(0.8)',
                        '-o-transform'      : 'translate(350px) scale(0.8)',
                        '-ms-transform'     : 'translate(350px) scale(0.8)',
                        'transform'         : 'translate(350px) scale(0.8)',
                        'opacity'           : 1,
                        'visibility'        : 'visible'
                    };
                    break;
                case 'center':
                    return {
                        '-webkit-transform' : 'translate(0px) scale(1)',
                        '-moz-transform'    : 'translate(0px) scale(1)',
                        '-o-transform'      : 'translate(0px) scale(1)',
                        '-ms-transform'     : 'translate(0px) scale(1)',
                        'transform'         : 'translate(0px) scale(1)',
                        'opacity'           : 1,
                        'visibility'        : 'visible'
                    };
                    break;
            };

        }
        else {

            switch( position ) {
                case 'outleft'  : 
                case 'outright' : 
                case 'left'     : 
                case 'right'    :
                    return {
                        'opacity'           : 0,
                        'visibility'        : 'hidden'
                    };
                    break;
                case 'center'   :
                    return {
                        'opacity'           : 1,
                        'visibility'        : 'visible'
                    };
                    break;
            };

        }

    },
    _navigate           : function( dir ) {

        if( this.supportTrans && this.isAnim )
            return false;

        this.isAnim = true;

        switch( dir ) {

            case 'next' :

                this.current    = this.$rightItm.index();

                // current item moves left
                this.$currentItm.addClass('dg-transition').css( this._getCoordinates('left') );

                // right item moves to the center
                this.$rightItm.addClass('dg-transition').css( this._getCoordinates('center') ); 

                // next item moves to the right
                if( this.$nextItm ) {

                    // left item moves out
                    this.$leftItm.addClass('dg-transition').css( this._getCoordinates('outleft') );

                    this.$nextItm.addClass('dg-transition').css( this._getCoordinates('right') );

                }
                else {

                    // left item moves right
                    this.$leftItm.addClass('dg-transition').css( this._getCoordinates('right') );

                }
                break;

            case 'prev' :

                this.current    = this.$leftItm.index();

                // current item moves right
                this.$currentItm.addClass('dg-transition').css( this._getCoordinates('right') );

                // left item moves to the center
                this.$leftItm.addClass('dg-transition').css( this._getCoordinates('center') );

                // prev item moves to the left
                if( this.$prevItm ) {

                    // right item moves out
                    this.$rightItm.addClass('dg-transition').css( this._getCoordinates('outright') );

                    this.$prevItm.addClass('dg-transition').css( this._getCoordinates('left') );

                }
                else {

                    // right item moves left
                    this.$rightItm.addClass('dg-transition').css( this._getCoordinates('left') );

                }
                break;  

        };

        this._setItems();

        if( !this.supportTrans )
            this.$currentItm.addClass('dg-center');

    },
    _startSlideshow     : function() {

        var _self   = this;

        this.slideshow  = setTimeout( function() {

            _self._navigate( 'next' );

            if( _self.options.autoplay ) {

                _self._startSlideshow();

            }

        }, this.options.interval );

    },
    destroy             : function() {

        this.$navPrev.off('.gallery');
        this.$navNext.off('.gallery');
        this.$wrapper.off('.gallery');

    }
};

var logError            = function( message ) {
    if ( this.console ) {
        console.error( message );
    }
};

$.fn.gallery            = function( options ) {

    if ( typeof options === 'string' ) {

        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 );

        this.each(function() {

            var instance = $.data( this, 'gallery' );

            if ( !instance ) {
                logError( "cannot call methods on gallery prior to initialization; " +
                "attempted to call method '" + options + "'" );
                return;
            }

            if ( !$.isFunction( instance[options] ) || options.charAt(0) === "_" ) {
                logError( "no such method '" + options + "' for gallery instance" );
                return;
            }

            instance[ options ].apply( instance, args );

        });

    } 
    else {

        this.each(function() {

            var instance = $.data( this, 'gallery' );
            if ( !instance ) {
                $.data( this, 'gallery', new $.Gallery( options, this ) );
            }
        });

    }

    return this;

};

})( jQuery );
```

This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
        <!-- Codrops top bar -->
            <!--/ Codrops top bar -->
  <section id="dg-container" class="dg-container">
    <div class="dg-wrapper">

      <a href="#"><img src="album1.jpg" alt="image05"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="album2.jpg" alt="image06"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="album3.jpg" alt="image07"></a>

    </div>
                <nav>   
                    <span class="dg-prev">&lt;</span>
                    <span class="dg-next">&gt;</span>
    </nav>
  </section>
</div>
```

EDIT:
Here is how the slider is being called from html page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $me=$('#dg-container').gallery({
                    autoplay    :   true
                });
//              console.log($me);

            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Have you managed to narrow down your issue at all?

Comment: Could you show your code on how do you call your gallery from document.ready ?

Comment: Added an Edit on how the slider is being called from html page.

Comment: What did you get when you did `console.log($me);`?

Comment: @ATOzTOA: Exactly I think may be he can directly call on swipe event $me._navigate('next'); But thats still a speculation ;)

Comment: $me._navigate('next');  didn't work and thrown error:  Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method '_navigate'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, `$navNext` and `$navPrev` are not functions, they are just `span` elements.

```
<span class="dg-prev">&lt;</span>
<span class="dg-next">&gt;</span>
```

You can use this

```
$(".dg-prev")
$(".dg-next")
```

to access these elements directly.

So, in your `swipe` code, call like this:

```
$(".dg-prev").click();
```